# A linear function from polynomial space to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be the standard basis for $Mat_{2,2}$ and $B'$ be the standard basis for $Pol_2$. Find the change of basis matrix for $$p(x) \rightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
p'(1) & 2p(0)\\
0 & p''(3)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In the solution it just directly gives $f(1)=E_{11}, f(x)=1E_{11}, f(x^2)=2E_{11}+2E_{22}$

My question is how were they calculated?

Comment: How indeed! I get that the polynomial $1$ maps under the linear map $f$ to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2\\0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ so that $f(1)=2E_{12}$. I did get that $x$  and $x^2$ map to the matrices that they claim, though. [You just have to work out for $p=1, p=x, p=x^2$ the values of $p'(1), 2p(0), p''(3)$ and express the three matrices in terms of the four $E_{ij}$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x) = a_0 +a_1x+a_2x^2$, then the map sends
$$
\begin{split}
a_0+a_1.x + a_2.x^2 &\to 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}a_1+2a_2 & 2a_0 \\ 
0 & 2a_2\end{array}\right)\\
&=a_0(2E_{12}) + a_1.E_{11}+ a_{2}.(2E_{11}+2E_{22}).
\end{split}
$$
thus the map obviously corresponds to the map of bases which sends $1$ to $2E_{12}$, $x\to E_11$ and $x^2$ to $2E_{12}$,